# Blackmagic Deck Link Quad 2 and Multiple Streams with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to accomplish streaming videos from 4 or more feeds on a local display from a DeckLink Quad 2 using `FFmpeg` as my transcoder. I can play two different videos (I only have two sources I can use simultaneously at my desk) fine, but struggle with connecting them into a single video *if* they are both on the DeckLink. The code I have for a single stream run as a `.bat` is below...

```
ffplay  -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 60 -pixel_format uyvy422 -f dshow -i video="Decklink Video Capture" \ pause
```

Reading most forums it would seem that sticking them together with a complex filter should work, as such:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 60 -vsync drop -f dshow -rtbufsize 150M -i video="Decklink Video Capture (5)" -i video="Decklink Video Capture" -i video="Decklink Video Capture (5)" -i video="Decklink Video Capture" -an -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[t]; [2:v][3:v]hstack[b]; [t][b]vstack" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -f mpegts pipe: | ffplay pipe: -vf scale=1280:720 \ pause
```

And, with two videos not from the DeckLink (i.e. DeckLink *and* file), it does work! But with both coming from the DeckLink I get the following in the console:

```
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Decklink Video Capture (5)':0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 71582788.354257, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (HDYC / 0x43594448), uyvy422(tv), 1280x720, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
video=Decklink Video Capture: No such file or directory
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing inputKB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

And that stream works running on its own too. So my optimistic concern is just that I'm using the wrong naming scheme; my only other idea is that I can't read two streams from the DeckLink card simultaneously (though I feel like I've read I can). Another concern is introduced here too: one of my streams does not run with frame rate set to 60fps, I need to set it to 59.94fps to work, otherwise it is a black screen.

Would I need to split these into multiple processed to run each stream simultaneously, save them to a temporary file or a pipeline, then combine them in another stream to display? I am concerned about the latency that program would introduce though. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have not enabled `USB Debugging` in your mobile.

So enable `Develope Mode` and `USB Debugging` the run the below command

```
 adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -
```

Wait 10 o 15 seconds then you should see your screen on your pc